# GCP Compute Engine on Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have developed a PHP site in Eclipse on localhost and have just transferred it to a GCP Compute Engine instance. To do this I've had to upload the site to a Storage Bucket and then on the SSH Shell for the instance in GCP used gsutil to transfer the files.

Now, as far as editting goes, is there a way for me to connect eclipse to the GCP instance and edit via Eclipse?

I don't want to have to, for every tweak, upload to the storage bucket and then copy file across to the instance. This would be most tedious.

I have created a firewall rule on the network to allow all traffic from my public IP to the Compute Engine instance (until I can lock it down once I've got the connection)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This article describes a procedure to editing remote files in Eclipse:

http://www.chrisdanford.com/blog/2010/05/19/edit-files-directly-over-sftp-in-eclipse-remote-system-explorer/

Quoting that article:

> From Eclipse: Help -> Install New Software. “Work with: -All available sites-“. In the search box type “remote system”. Check “Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime”, click Next to proceed with the install.
>   After the wizard completed, click Window -> Open Perspective -> Remote System Explorer.  Right-click in Remote Systems, choose New Connection, type in your details.  After you connect, expand “Sftp Files” and you’ll be able to open remote files in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can forward ports over SSH using the gcloud sdk

gcloud compute ssh example-instance \
    --project my-project \
    --zone us-central1-a \
    -- -L 2222:localhost:8888

Once you have this setup you can connect direct in Eclipse

See details:

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#Port%20forwarding%20over%20SSH